# Can we get app_name from string.xml programatically in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

This app has its own unique name for each flavor. So I am wondering if I can pull than unique name from each flavor's `string.xml` file (variable `app_name`) which I will then set as APK name.

At this moment, all examples I saw create APK name as hardcoded string (method `variant.outputFile.name.replace`).

So can this be done programatically?

So I don't have to do it like this

```
if (variant.productFlavors[0].name.equals("flavorA")) {
   flavorName = "Flavor A name";
} else if ...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, but we have to stick to hardcoded strings. If it changes in the future, I will update this reply.